# QEMU reset VM without libvirt

Tags: qemu, libvirt

How to reset VM by QEMU without libvirt?
I need to reset VM in VDSM hook "before_vm_start"
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch to the qemu monitor console (by default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>), and type in the `system_reset` command.

Comment: Thank you for answer!
But I want to do it from python code.
For example, I get disk info:
cmd_disk_info = ['qemu-img', 'info', path_to_image]
    disk_info = subprocess.run(cmd_disk_info, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                               check=True).stdout.decode("utf-8")
How to reset VM from python?

Comment: you attach to the monitor port and do the same.

Comment: Maybe there is an example, how to attach qemu-monitor in python? I'm newbie in QEMU, libvirt etc....

Comment: honestly, then why are you running QEMU from python directly? use libvirt from Python, and all this is abstracted for you...